# 'Task' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, async-await, swift-playground

I'm trying new Swift 5.5 await async features and I get that compilation error when I try this in a Playground:

```swift
let task1 = Task {
    // ...
}
```

> 'Task' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

I got the example from https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/233/whats-new-in-swift-5-5

Any idea?

Comment: Which version of playground are you using?

Comment: Xcode 13.0 beta

Comment: XCode 13 beta 3 uses `Task` already and there is a warning for `async`: async(priority:operation:) is deprecated: async was replaced by Task.init and will be removed shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the current syntax is `async { ... }` instead of `Task { ... }` with the intention that the `Task` syntax is to be used in some future build.

Comment: I think the same, this article was written before WWDC 21. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you are referencing another Foundation named Task.

```
_Concurrency.Task {
     //brabra
}
```

Did you use it like this

```
typealias Task = _Concurrency.Task
```

Specify it like this and use it